# How i allow remote access to my python API?

Tags: python, rest, server, localhost, twisted

I have built a python RESTful API which is using Klein/Twisted. Instead of using localhost I want to allow access to my public IP address, so everyone can connect to my API. (This is temporary for testing until I get it hosted on AWS EC2).

I have been very lost on how to do this and have followed tutorials such as forwarding port 80 but it doesn't seem to work. I do apologize if my knowledge is limited as I am not very proficient in this field. Could someone please point me to a resource?

This is the code I want to change to my public IP and port 80 so my API is accessible.

```
endpoint_description = "tcp:port=%s:interface=localhost" % 8090
endpoint = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, endpoint_description)
```

Comment: 1) Don't use `%` interpolation. Use Python 3 and `.format()` (or even better f-strings if you're on Python 3.6) 2) If you are behind a router you need to forward port 80 to your machine. But that router must have a public IP address. If you have a router plugged into a university network this won't work (most likely, because that router won't have a public ip address). The easiest way to get up and running is an AWS instance or google cloud. With Spectre and Meltdown, I wouldn't want to open my computer up to the public internet like that

Comment: @BaileyParker thank you so much! I have it running on ec2, just not sure what to change with ```localhost```, do i change it to my ec2 public ip? and port as 80? in my security groups all ports are open

Comment: Yep that's right. You can also change it to `0.0.0.0` (bind on all ports).

Comment: @Bailey Bind on all *IPs* (if your machine happens to have multiple). Binding on all *ports* would be breaking everything left and right.

Comment: I previously accessed my API on my computer using localhost:8090/example, by changing the field as stated above, this dosen't just allow me to access it now by <public-ec2-ip>:80/example does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for the IPv4/TCP and IPv6/TCP endpoints is to listen on all interfaces.  All you have to do is not restrict it by specifying an interface:

```
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor

endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8090)
```

Notice also that there's no need to do string mashing in your example.  Just instantiate the endpoint you want and pass it the arguments you want.  The string syntax is for creating an endpoint from a description from a system that only supports strings (CLI, config files, etc).